# X11 change screen orientation Debian

Tags: c, linux, shell, debian, x11

I want to change screen orientation between portrait and landscape, through Debian command line, shell script or C code. Windowing system is X11. I have searched the Web but without success.

```
xrandr -o left
```

Response:

> ```
> X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
>   Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
>   Minor opcode of failed request:  2 (RRSetScreenConfig)
>   Serial number of failed request:  14
>   Current serial number in output stream:  14
> ```

If I want do anything with xrandr it shows "`xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default`" only.

LCD is connected on LVDS connector. My xorg.conf is

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "BlankTime"  "0"
    Option "StandbyTime"  "0"
    Option "SuspendTime"  "0"
    Option "OffTime"  "0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier      "fbdev display"
    Driver          "fbdev"
    #Option "Rotate" "CCW"
    Option "Rotate" "RandRRotation" "On"
EndSection
```

Is it possible to rotate my display?

Comment: I thing I forgot to include. I can do it as static change orientation by adding in xorg.conf in device section Option "Rotate" "CCW".    After this I have to restart display manager so screen becomes blank for a time.    But requirement is to change change it dynamically without restat display manager.

Comment: Have you a user interface ? Under GNOME, it is possible to make it using configuration panel. Just try it from here (or anything else graphical). If there is not possible, perhaps you are missing a pilot.

Answer (score 0):

Not all X11 drivers supports Xrandr API. Some drivers do not support changing this at runtime at all, while others have non-standard ways to perform this. An example would be a binary closed source driver with its own utility.

Answer (score 0):

There are many graphical front-ends to xrandr, that simplify its use.  These front-ends may not always be available, especially when using more minimalist window managers.

For those situations, it's handy to know some options that can be used to avoid the overhead of installing multiple libraries and unwanted cruft.

#### Some useful options

```
$ xrandr -q # With one monitor connected
```

> ```
> Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
> LVDS connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
>    1366x768       60.0*+
>    1280x720       59.9  
>    1152x768       59.8  
>    1024x768       59.9  
>    800x600        59.9  
>    848x480        59.7  
>    720x480        59.7  
>    640x480        59.4  
> VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
> ```

After attaching a second monitor we also get this listed:

> ```
> HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 16mm x 9mm
>    1920x1080i     30.0 +   25.0     30.0  
>    1920x1080      24.0*    24.0  
>    1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
>    1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
>    1440x480i      30.0  
>    832x624        74.6  
>    800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
>    720x576        50.0  
>    720x576i       25.0  
>    720x480        60.0     59.9  
>    720x480i       30.0     30.0  
>    640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0     59.9
> ```

#### Some useful options

- **`--auto`**      Enable connected monitor with preferred mode
- **`--mode mode`** Set the resolution, using a value reported with xrandr -q
- **`--rate rate`**     Set the refresh rate
- **`--left-of`**  **`--right-of`** **`--above`** **`--below`** **`--same-as`**
              Set the position of a monitor relative to another
- **`--off`**           Turn output to monitor off

#### Some toys

Use normal to restore normality.  Each command is relative to normal, so 4 rotates right wont fully rotate, each will duplicate the first command... try it!

- **`--reflect <normal|x|y|xy>`**
- **`--rotate <normal|left|right|inverted>`**